# Comments mislocated under question migration?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, migration

[This question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/9963) was just migrated from Academia.SE to CogSci.SE.  I cannot view the post as I originally saw it on Academia, but some comments have apparently been moved from a (now deleted?) answer to comments on the question.  Here is a screenshot of the current migrated question with comments:

[image]

When I left my comment on the question (the last one listed above), there was only 1 other comment.  As I recall, all of the comments (certainly the 2nd one) came from an answer which is no longer there, and I suppose was either deleted/removed during the migration or subsequently.

Why did an answer disappear but its comments become comments to the OP?  My expectation is that said answer together with associated comments should either be all migrated together, or they should all be removed.  (In this particular situation, I don't know why 1 of 2 existing answers was migrated but another wasn't.)

Is this some sort of bug, or an effect of intentionally trying to preserve comments on an answer without the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments appear on the question now because a CogSci moderator converted the answer to a comment and also moved the answer's comments to the question:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Can moderators also edit comments? If so, I would expect the second comment to be edited into shape, at least adding a `@-reply` in the beginning so that it doesn't look like it's referring to the question.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I didn't know moderators could do this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just edited it a bit, but didn't add an `@` reply; I didn't want to ping the original author again on something they had already addressed.